# JavaScript & Stripe | PaymentMethods

Tags: javascript, python, django, stripe-payments

I Have no experience with Javascript and I've been working on an integration with Stripe. I'm slowly able to learn how their code is working but need advice on how to get the result sent back with the form to go into my next function.

Here is the old code that will work and sends back the 'token' for a single payment:

```
var purchaseButton = document.getElementById('purchase-button');
            purchaseButton.classList.add('is-loading');
            stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    // Inform the customer that there was an error.
                    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                    purchaseButton.classList.remove('is-loading');
                } else {
                    // Send the token to your server.
                    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
```

This comes back with 'stripetoken' in post, I want to use my newer code below and get the same effect, but retrieving the result.paymentMethod described here: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/create_payment_method

Here is my newer code that is talking to stripe, I just need to get the resulting information for the call

```
var purchaseButton = document.getElementById('purchase-button');
            purchaseButton.classList.add('is-loading');
            stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: card,
            })
            .then(function (result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    // Inform the customer that there was an error.
                    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                    purchaseButton.classList.remove('is-loading');
                } else {
                    // Send the token to your server.
                     paymentmethod(result.token);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    function paymentmethod(token) {
        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'paymentmethod');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.paymentMethod);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
```

This is my basic approach to understanding JS. I was thinking with this code it would come back with a post object called 'paymentmethod' and the value of that would be 'result'

Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close here! If you're creating a Payment Method instead of a Token, in your promise you can get the Payment Method with `result.paymentMethod` instead of `result.token`. In your `paymentmethod` function you'd want to append the id of the payment method (`pm_xxxyyyyzzz`), given that you call the variable passed to this function `token`, try `token.id`.

When debugging javascript, I always recommend using your [browser console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console) and printing objects out to the console with `console.log` statements (e.g. `console.log(result);` to understand the structure of this object).

Beyond that, you might have a look at Stripe's [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/web) and [samples](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment) to see best practices for these new payment flows. While you can still collect card details using a payment method as above, Stripe's new flows may simplify things and are better suited to handling conditions like cards that require 3D Secure authentication.

Comment: Great! I made those changes, and now I am getting an object coming back of paymentmethod but the value is undefined. So, I'm guessing that means I'm not specifying exactly what stripe is sending back to me. I will use the console statements as you've shown me. Thanks for your help!